# iOS 7 partial swipe back issue

Tags: ios7, uinavigationcontroller, swipe, back

In my app while using swipe to back in iOS 7 my viewcontroller's will disappear gets called while swipping itself. So if I leave in the middle of swiping again viewwillappear is getting called. How to avoid this? I don't want disappear to be called while swiping.